# What should I get before summoning the penguin mothership?

Tags: starbound

So, on my old character (before the wipe) I summoned the penguins when I wasn't ready. Boy, was that a mistake. I want to summon them again, but what weapons and armor should I get first? And are the penguins still Level 9? Because every other mob doesn't have a level. I'm not sure copper armor can be upgraded into silver. And I couldn't go to different threat level planets because they are now all level 1.

Comment: I know bombs dealt the bulk of the damage I was able to do myself. I ran out of them though, and I don't know of any way to get them other than finding them. But someone who's done it can probably speak to it better than I can.

Comment: But wasn't that question asked before the update?

Comment: @JumpingCactus Yes, and therefore the answers in it are no longer current and should be edited. The question is the same, but the correct answer is different.